# How to calculate number of times a condition is checked in FOR loop

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop

I am writing a program for insertion sort.

I want to know how much time the "condition i.e `a[k]>temp`" in for loop has been checked to determine the number of comparisons done.

How to find it?

```
    int i,j,k,moves=0,comparison=0;
    for(j=1;j<arr_length;j++)
        {
            temp=a[j];
            for(k=j-1;k>=0 && a[k]>temp;k--)
             {
                 moves+=1;
                 a[k+1]=a[k];
                 a[k]=temp;
             }
        }

        printf("No. of Moves%d",moves);
        printf("Comparisons%d",comparison);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of getting the correct value is to use a additional variable in a comma delimited list:

```
size_t count= 0;

for(k=j-1;k>=0 && ( count++ , a[k]>temp ) ; k--)
```

This will evaluate both `count++` and `a[k]>temp`, but the value used in the comparison will be only `a[k]>temp`.

Comment: variable `moves` only records the number of times an elements are swapped. It is not used to check the number of times comparison is made.

Comment: @Poo I have edited the answer, but hopefully you understand the general idea.

Comment: Yes, I got your idea,I replaced `count++` with `comparison++` inside my code but not getting the correct answer. i.e arr_length * (arr_length - 1) / 2

Comment: @Poo The comma delimited counter works correctly. Perhaps some of your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Curious why this answer uses `size_t` vs. `unsigned` or any other type?

Comment: Nice use of `,` operator.

Comment: It worked, only 1 more line was needed to make it work.  Putting the  code here...                                                                                     
  int i,j,k,moves=0,comparison=0,temp_cmp=0;
  for(j=1;j<arr_length;j++)
            {
                temp=a[j];    
    for(k=j-1;k>=0 && ( temp_cmp++ , a[k]>temp ) ; k--)
                 {
                     moves+=1;
                     a[k+1]=a[k];
                     a[k]=temp;
                 }
     comparison+=temp_cmp;
            }
   
   printf("No. of Moves%d",moves);
   printf("Comparisons%d",comparison);

Comment: @reader I am not able to understand how this comma operator is working here.If I give an sorted array in input then i get the exact answer, for unsorted array, I am not getting expected answer i.e: arr_length * (arr_length - 1) / 2

Answer (score 1):

You're already having `k`. Use it.

After the `for()` loop, if `k>= 0`, then subtract the current value of `k` from the initial value of `k` [Here `j-1`]. This will give you the number of times `a[k]>temp` [`for()` loop condition check] has been executed.

Answer (score -1):

I would put the comparison 'a[k] > temp' into a function that increments a counter.

```
bool check( int &counter, int lhs, int rhs )
{
    ++counter;
    return lhs > rhs;
}
```

...

```
int counter = 0;
```

...

```
for (k=j-1;k>=0 && check( counter, a[k], temp );k--)
```

Comment: Seems a bit needlessly bloated. Also, this isn't C++.

Answer (score -1):

To begin with, the source of all problems is obscure loops. Start by fixing your program into something more readable, where the 3 loop statements are kept simple. Also, always count from 0 and up or you'll burn yourself on array indexing bugs over and over.

```
  int moves = 0;
  int comparisons = 0;

  for(int j=0; j<arr_length; j++)
  {
    temp = a[j+1];

    for(int k=j; k>=0; k--)
    {
      comparisons++;
      if(a[k] <= temp)
      {
        break;
      }

      moves++;
      a[k+1]=a[k];
      a[k]=temp;
    }
  }
```

Cleaning up your code instead of obfuscating it even further is always the sensible thing to do.